# Create WinSCP SessionOptions using ASP Session variable in way it can be reused between multiple methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session-variables, winscp-net

I am facing issue while creating WinSCP `Session[Options]` variable in C# ASP page.

I have login page where I am defining session variables.

```
namespace HLR_Handling
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["sftpHostName"] = "x.x.x.x";
            Session["sftpUserName"] = "tempuser";  
        }
    }
}
```

and in `Profile_Search` page I am trying to assign that variable value to `SessionOption` parameter but here I am getting below error.

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Session.get' for sessionoptions

```
public partial class Profile_Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        HostName = Session["sftpHostName"].ToSTring(),
        UserName = Session["sftpUserName"],
        Password = "xxxxxx",
        PortNumber = 22,
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa x:x:X:Xxxxxxxx"
    };

    protected void btnHLR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Session session = new Session())
        {
            // Connect
            session.Open(sessionOptions);

            // ....        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `SessionOptions` declaration into your method.

```
protected void btnHLR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = Session["sftpHostName"].ToSTring(),
            UserName = Session["sftpUserName"],
            Password = "xxxxxx",
            PortNumber = 22,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa x:x:X:Xxxxxxxx"
        };

        // Connect
        session.Open(sessionOptions);

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

If you need to use the session options repeatedly, you can factor out the creation to a method:

```
protected SessionOptions CreateSessionOptions()
{
    return new SessionOptions
    {
        Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
        HostName = Session["sftpHostName"].ToSTring(),
        UserName = Session["sftpUserName"],
        Password = "xxxxxx",
        PortNumber = 22,
        SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa x:x:X:Xxxxxxxx"
    };
}

protected void btnHLR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        // Connect
        session.Open(CreateSessionOptions());

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

Or you can factor our whole session creation:

```
protected Session CreateSession()
{
    Session session = new Session();
    try
    {
        SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
        {
            Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
            HostName = Session["sftpHostName"].ToSTring(),
            UserName = Session["sftpUserName"],
            Password = "xxxxxx",
            PortNumber = 22,
            SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa x:x:X:Xxxxxxxx"
        };

        // Connect
        session.Open(sessionOptions);
    }
    catch
    {
        session.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
    return session;
}

protected void btnHLR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Session session = CreateSession())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```